# bash script check element of an array if its a Linux command or not

Tags: linux, bash

if i have an array of strings 
how do i check if any element in this array represent a Linux command !!

for example

```
declare -a array( 'clear' 'cp' 'hello this is a normal string' 'who')
```

who the check would be using 
`for t in "${array[@]}
 do
  if [.........]`
$array[t] # execute the command

thanks for consideration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `which`:

```
 path=$(which $command)
 if [ $? = 0 ] ; then
     echo "command $command was found"
 fi
```

However, it will just find commands which are located inside directories listed in your `$PATH` environment variable.